# Verifying a Websokcet connection with Python

Tags: python, json, api, websocket, python-requests

How can I write a piece of code where if there is an error with the connection to a `websocket` between the remote host and the server, it would restart the piece of code until the connection until the resultant is not an error? Can i do a while loop or something that could verify the connection?

Websocket Connections:

```
ws_inverse_unauth = WebSocket(inverse, subscriptions=inverse_subs)
ws_unauth = WebSocket(usdt_perp, subscriptions=usdt_subs)
```

Code:

```
#ws connection to bybit API
inverse= "wss://stream-testnet.bybit.com/realtime"
usdt_perp = "wss://stream.bybit.com/realtime_public"
#subscriptions
inverse_subs = ["klineV2.1.BTCUSD"]
usdt_subs = ["candle.1.BTCUSDT"]
#configuring the websocket connections
ws_inverse_unauth = WebSocket(inverse, subscriptions=inverse_subs)
ws_unauth = WebSocket(usdt_perp, subscriptions=usdt_subs)
```

Comment: What keeps you from re-issuing the call that created the error?

Comment: The error is `[WinError 10054]`

Comment: Okay, what does that error tell you?  Does it generate an exception?  Can you trap it?